# What HTTP status should be used in the response?

Tags: java, rest, express, http, https

I have a POST rest end point for resource Post, which updates a field named "status" on the Post resource only if there is no other post in "review" status. However if a user tries to update a Post to "review" status when there is already a Post in review, what status should be returned?

I can think of 3 options:

1. 403: As it is a forbidden action when there is already a Post in review state.
2. 400: As the request from the user to update the status of a Post when there is already a Post in "review" status, so the request to update the status of a Post is Bad request.
3. 200: Send OK response with a JSON data, which has fields { success: false, err: 'Not allowed as some other Post is already in Review' }

Which is more REST way of handling this? Is there some other status that can be used apart from these?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, and thus off-topic for SO. Some people like to extend their application logic states into HTTP status codes (your #1 and #2), others prefer to have their HTTP status codes just reflect the result of the HTTP layer, not the application layer. Both approaches have pros and cons, and adherents both academic and pragmatic. :-)

Comment: Ditto... this is opinion. That said, I would lean toward 304 (Not Modified), 204 (No Content), or maybe 409 (Conflict). Honestly, a 4XX code seems unnecessary, but up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The 400 with a string response explaining why the Post is 'Bad' is the best option. consider something like

> Unable to Change Status, Another Post is Already in Review

***Please* do not use** 200 (OK) with a body that explains some other-than-ok condition. I see this all too often and want to chew my fingers off every time!

403s are best used for permissions restrictions such as

> Unable to Change Status, Upgrade Your Account to Allow for Updating
>   Post Status

--even though this does not apply in your case